# "No matter how large the finite set" OR "No matter how large the finite set **is**"

Tags: ellipsis

In [Book *Mathematics for Computer Science*](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/readings/MIT6_042JF10_notes.pdf):

> The key to remember is that you can’t check a claim about an infinite set by checking a finite set of its elements, **no matter how large the finite set.**

Should the last sentence be *no matter how large the finite set **is***?
Or both forms are correct?

Comment: Both versions are fine. It's just the standard "linguistic device" called ***deletion** [of **predictable / repeated** elements].* In your context, the relevant ***noun*** is just as predictable as the verb, so that final clause could quite naturally have been reduced to just ***...no matter how large.***

Answer (score 1):

Answered in the comments:

> "Both versions are fine. It's just the standard "linguistic device" called deletion [of predictable / repeated elements]. In your context, the relevant noun is just as predictable as the verb, so that final clause could quite naturally have been reduced to just ...no matter how large." – FumbleFingers

Comment: It is not fair to use his answer to get his points. You should encourage him to post, not take his post.

Comment: ...He do often, give excellent and clear answers like this in a comment. Which is a pity as they would be more useful as an answer and would result in more answered questions! Come on @FumbleFingers! Please post!